# fetch all images from photo library using photos framework

Tags: swift2, uicollectionview

I have an issue about the PHCachingImageManager, how can i handle thousands of images in my custom collection view?

My code in viewWillAppear is as below.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    for i in 0..<phasset.count - 1 {
        let getAsset = phasset[i]
        catchingImage.startCachingImages(for: [getAsset], targetSize: CGSize(width:125,height:125), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil)

    }

}
```

And my code in the cellForIrem in collection view is as below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? thumbNailCell

    catchingImage.requestImage(for: phasset[indexPath.row], targetSize: CGSize(width:125,height:125), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil) { (img, nil) in
        cell?.ImageView.image = img!
    }
    return cell!
}
```

But i am also getting the memory issue when i load all images from photo library.

And when i resize the images to 100.0 X 100.0 its work good but when i save each image in fileSystem (NSFileManager) i save image not good ,have no resolution and no good quality please any way to solve this problem for fetch all images without memory warning

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use two different apis to fix your problem.
While rendering to the cell use the catchinImage api as you mentioned above

```
catchingImage.requestImage(for: phasset[indexPath.row], targetSize: CGSize(width:100,height:100), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil) { (img, nil) in
    cell?.ImageView.image = img!
}
```

But when it comes to saving the image to fileSystem you should use PHImageManager instead of catchingmanager

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES //download from iCloud if required

PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(phasset[indexPath.row], options: options) { (data, _, _, _) in
    let retrievedData = NSData(data: retrievedCFData)
    retrievedData.write(toFile:filepath atomically:NO)
}
```

Comment: thank you very much my friend it's work then when i need to display it the images which i save it in the fileSystem i need to resize images is this right?